# Can't upload images in Joomla 1.5.22

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Joomla 1.5.22 new installation, no extensions added. I've only configured the Global Configuration pages. For some reason, I can't upload any pictures, either in articles or in the media manager. "Start Upload" does nothing, it just sits there.

The only thing I could find on this was a folder permissions issue and and so I set Images and all sub-folders to 777, but that still didn't help.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this and how to get it to allow for pictures to be uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On global configuration, in media settings  you've enabled the flash uploader which disallows to upload the files for some reason. Disable it, now you'll be allowed to upload files again

Comment: This worked! Not sure why and now if I'll be able to upload flash files, but at least I can now upload pictures!

Comment: I am using 2.5.1 Stable and.I have the same problem mentiones above.And i could not find media setting in global conf

Answer (score 2):

First off change your folder settings back from 777 to something more secure (664 or 775). Then Prakash could be correct in that the flash uploader is not working on your system and you can disable it and use the normal file view uploader. Try that and let us know.

Comment: Folders should be 755, files 644. If your flash plugin is newer than v9 then the flash uploader does not work. You will have to do it one at a time.

Comment: @brent yup good point, Joomla! security doc says folders 755 and files 664. Now of course this is relative as some times you might change permissions for specific business reasons however the suggestion is not to.

Comment: I generally recommend using the recommended permissions as a debugging tool as well. If it doesn't work with those permissions, there is probably something set up wrong.

Comment: thanks. permissions were originally at 755 so I set them back and used Prakash's suggestion and it worked. Thanks Brent also for the details on flash version9.